# generating part of the URL to get access

Tags: java, jsf

assuming I have the following existing url

http://www.seusite.com.br/index.php?pagina=noticia&id_noticia=12

I am creating a form for not having to send the url to the User, the form will have two fields, id_noticia and pagina, that when it fill the form if it type (noticia, 12) go to the following url
http://www.seusite.com.br/index.php?pagina=noticia&id_noticia=12

I'm using java with jsf, below the code which created two variables id and page where and inserted by xhtml, want to know how do I enter these variables: the existing url to be able to access.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <h:form>
    <h:outputText value="pagina:"></h:outputText>
        <h:inputText id="email" value="#{test.pagina}"></h:inputText>

        <h:outputText value="id_noticia:"></h:outputText>
        <h:inputText id="email" value="#{test.id_noticia}"></h:inputText>


        <h:commandLink>Go</h:commandLink>
        </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this site is not yours, right? So, what you want is to have a JSF submit a form to an external site. In this way, you could get a simple form like:

```
<form action="http://www.seusite.com.br/index.php">
    <input type="text" name="pagina" value="type pagina" />
    <input type="text" name="id_noticia" value="type id_noticia" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, this site and just a demonstration, what I want and get a url where it has some parameters, if I go to your browser and type the url and fill in the parameters then can access the page, but I want to be able to fill this formulator in one page without being directly the url when I fill in the fields of the form it will fill the values in the url completing it